# How to keep double slashes in IIS rewrite?

Tags: iis, web-config, url-rewriting

I notice IIS removes double slashes, but I want to keep them.

```
<rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite to go.php">
        <match url="^go/(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="go.php?url={R:1}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

In this case `go/http://google.com` is redirected to `go.php?url=http:/google.com`, notice the single slash. I can rewrite go.php so it adds the extra slash but.. Can it be fixed from within Web.config?

Comment: Try four instead of two.

Comment: Tried it, four was also reduced to one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go/http://google.com is not a valid url. You need to have it url encoded first, i.e. go/http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com